# How to detect if Kali is run from Live CD in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, kali-linux, livecd, liveusb

What is the most reliable way to detect if Kali is run from Live CD or installed to disk?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to do:

```
root@kali:~# df -kh |grep live
/dev/sr0        3.0G  3.0G     0 100% /run/live/medium
/dev/loop0      2.7G  2.7G     0 100% /run/live/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
tmpfs           5.8G   24M  5.8G   1% /run/live/overlay
```

This works because live-boot is being used as a basis for the Live USB disc.

More info can be found here: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/live-boot-doc/live-boot.7.en.html
This also explains the overlay shim.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: Ok, good idea I will integrate that into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For "ubuntu galaxy distros" the trick is to detect the virtual CDROM apt updater ;) dunno if kali contains that.

```
if [ `cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -q "deb cdrom:" ; echo $?` == "0" ];
then
 echo "LIVECD IS DETECTED"
else
 echo "LIVECD IS NOT DETECTED"
fi
```